# « Montre-le-moi », « dis-le-moi »

Tags: trait-d-union

« Rends-le-moi » ou « rends-le moi » ?

Grévisse écrit « Montre-les-moi, Dis-le-moi. »

Ionesco écrit:

> « Passez-la moi au bout du fil. »

Ce que Grévisse cite et commente d'un [sic] montrant sa réprobation (juste après « passez-la »)

Or, j'ai toujours vu écrit « Montre-les », « Dis-le », même avec un COI derrière.
Ai-je mal vu ?

Hypercorrection ou règle grammaticale qui se perd ?

Answer (score 3):

La règle indiquée par les grammaires prescriptives<sup>1</sup> est d'utiliser des traits d'union devant chacun des deux pronoms:

> Rends-le-moi !
>
> Montre-les-moi !
>
> Dis-le-moi !

En pratique, on constate que si cette règle était plutôt bien respectée au XIXᵉ siècle, c'était beaucoup moins le cas au XXᵉ où le deuxième trait d'union est souvent absent. Depuis le début du XXIᵉ, un regain de présence de ce deuxième trait d'union est cependant notable. On ne peut donc pas parler d'une règle grammaticale qui se perd puisque la tendance est au contraire à un respect grandissant.

L'absence des deux traits d'union ne se rencontre pas et peut donc être considérée comme fautive.

> *Rends le moi !

---

Quelques Ngrams :

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note: si le deuxième pronom n'est pas lié au verbe à l'impératif mais à un infinitif, il n'est pas précédé d'un trait d'union:

> Laisse-le nous suivre !

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>Par exemple :

- [Académie Française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/DNP0787)

- [OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4206)

- [Bescherelle](http://bescherelle.ca/imperatif-et-pronoms/)

- [Le Figaro](https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/frtraitunionimperatif.php)

- [Kalmbach](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/316.html)</sub>

Answer (score -6):

**I** Dis-le moi,  Dis-le-moi, montre-le moi, montre-le-moi

Un [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Montre-les-moi%2CDis-le-moi%2CMontre-les+moi%2CDis-le+moi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CMontre%20-%20les%20-%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDis%20-%20le%20-%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CMontre%20-%20les%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDis%20-%20le%20moi%3B%2Cc0) montre que l'usage fluctue, qu'il n'y a pas de règle ou plutôt que les deux possibilités doivent pour l'instant être considérées comme correctes; j'ai l'impression de ne pas trouver le second trait d'union  dans ce que je lis, mais c'est néanmoins l'usage d'un second trait d'union qui est majoritaire.

Ce principe d'option possible d'utilisation d'un second trait d'union est vrai pour les cas suivants.

- [rends-le moi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rends-le+moi%2Crends-le-moi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crends%20-%20le%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crends%20-%20le%20-%20moi%3B%2Cc0), [fais-le moi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fais-le+moi%2Cfais-le-moi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfais%20-%20le%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfais%20-%20le%20-%20moi%3B%2Cc0), [donne-le moi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=donne-le+moi%2Cdonne-le-moi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdonne%20-%20le%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdonne%20-%20le%20-%20moi%3B%2Cc0), [passe-le moi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=passe-le+moi%2Cpasse-le-moi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpasse%20-%20le%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpasse%20-%20le%20-%20moi%3B%2Cc0), [prête-le-moi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pr%C3%AAte-le+moi%2Cpr%C3%AAte-le-moi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%AAte%20-%20le%20-%20moi%3B%2Cc0), [envoie-le moi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=envoie-le+moi%2Cenvoie-le-moi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cenvoie%20-%20le%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cenvoie%20-%20le%20-%20moi%3B%2Cc0), [apprends-le moi](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=apprends-le+moi%2Capprends-le-moi&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Capprends%20-%20le%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capprends%20-%20le%20-%20moi%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Capprends%20-%20le%20moi%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Capprends%20-%20le%20-%20moi%3B%2Cc0)

Il ne s'agit pas d'une règle qui se perde puisqu'il n'y a pas de règle. Puisqu'il n'y a aucune infraction à une règle je n'appellerais pas cela non plus de l'hypercorrection.

Personnellement, je ne conçois aucune utilité dans l'utilisation de ces traits d'union et je me passerais aussi bien du premier que du second.

Comment: "dis le" n'est pas correct par contre. Le minimum qu'on considère comme correct à l'école et à l'université, c'est écoute-le, etc...

Comment: @LPH *Dis le* (à l'impératif) est incorrect. Il faudrait montrer des sources plus convaincantes que des ngrams bancals qui n'excluent pas *je **dis le** vrai* et *je vous le **dis, le** royaume du Père ...* avant d'affirmer le contraire.

Comment: *On ne trouve pas du tout la forme avec le trait d'union entre les pronoms* : surtout quand on écrit *apprends* avec un P et deux R et que la recherche exclut de fait l'essentiel des phrases à l'impératif.

Comment: @jlliagre Exact, merci d'avoir vérifié cet ngram soigneusement.

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui t'incite à affirmer qu'il n'y a pas de règle ? As-tu fait des recherches là-dessus ?

Comment: @jlliagre Il n'y a pas besoin de plus que les ngram, qui montrent que par courtes périodes se succédant, tantôt c'est une forme qui est le plus utilisée tantôt c'est l'autre. Les deux sont acceptées donc ; il n'y a pas de règle dans le sens d'imposer soit l'une soit l'autre. Bien sûr on peut dire que la règle est que l'usage est libre, mais je ne crois que cela soit une règle explicite.

Comment: L'Académie française, le Bescherelle, l'OQLF, ça te dis quelque chose ?

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, ça me dit bien quelque chose, mais apparemment pour une multitude d'utilisateur de la langue française il n'y en a pas  un seul, que ce soit l'Académie ou un autre qui leur dise quoi que ce soit ; pourquoi être plus royaliste que l'utilisateur roi dont on voit les règles qu'il choisit dans les ngrams ?

Comment: Même s'ils sont liés, ne confonds pas règles (prescriptions) et usage (libre). Ne pas respecter une règle de grammaire n'est pas une infraction mais ce n'est pas parce que des règles sont parfois ou souvent ignorées qu'elles n'existent pas.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102682/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-lph).